# Deduced conflicting types without template

Tags: operator-overloading, c++17, type-deduction, deduction-guide

I'm trying to create a type that can store either an int, a double, or an uint, like so:

```cpp
struct Value
{
    /*...*/

    Value& operator=(const int value) { /*...*/ }
    Value& operator=(const double value) { /*...*/ }
    Value& operator=(const uint value) { /*...*/ }

    operator int() const { /*...*/ }
    operator double() const { /*...*/ }
    operator uint() const { /*...*/ }
}
```

I got errors about "deduced conflicting types" when I'm trying to use it. I read somewhere that "deduction guide" can help but it seems to require template. My type doesn't need template.

Is there a solution to use this Value type without the need to cast it in int,double or uint everytime?

```cpp
Value v;
v=123;

// I would like to type:
std::clamp(v,0,1234); // error

// But I need to type:
std::clamp(int(v),0,1234); // ok
```

I also have the same kind of problem with operator (with different error messages)

```cpp
int x=v+12;
```

I think I should add more operator overloading, but I don't found which one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> // I would like to type:

> ```
> std::clamp(v,0,1234); // error
> ```

Try with

```
 // .......VVVVV
 std::clamp<int>(v, 0, 1234);
```

The problem is the signature of `std::clamp()` is

```
 template<class T>
 constexpr const T& clamp( const T& v, const T& lo, const T& hi );
```

so if you call it without explicating `T`,

```
 std::clamp(v, 0, 1234);
```

the template type `T` is deduced `Value`, from `v`, and `int`, from `0` and from `1234`.

Given the conflicting types, you get an error.

If you explicit the template type

```
 // .......VVVVV
 std::clamp<int>(v, 0, 1234);
```

there is no more deduction, the compiler expect an `int` in first position so the `operator int ()` is called over `v`.